# When to use an index

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a general rule of thumb or formula as to when it would be useful to use an index?

For example, in the following case, it would be obvious to add an INDEX on the `id` column:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1iuhiasdf89384h'
```

However, the following would probably not useful on `is_qualified` if it has 2 possible values:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE is_qualified=1
```

What about an item that has 10 [0-9] possible values? 100 values [0-99]? When do you usually want to add an index, and how does this relate to the `cardinality` ?

Comment: A very general "rule" is to index all primary key columns and any columns that participate in a foreign key relationship. After that, index as performance of queries dictate.

Comment: You add an index when your query does a table scan instead of going right to the row(s) you need.  Generally, the higher your cardinality, the better your index.  In your specific case, no index for 10 or less possible values, an index for 11 or higher possible values.  The exact number depends on your relational database and the performance of your database computer.  Add the index and measure the increase or decrease in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, the reason the optimizer chooses to use an index in a `where` clause is to reduce the number of data pages being read.  So, if your data is spread randomly over the pages, the important question is how many records are on each page and how many records is the filter selecting.

Say there are 100 records on each page.  Then a *random* selection of one percent of records will likely select (almost) all the pages.  In this situation, reading the pages and doing the filtering on the pages will likely be faster than using an index, because just about all the data pages will be read anyway.  T

So, for most tables, a query that returns one or a handful of records is going to be better off with an index.  Queries that return lots of records may not benefit from an index.  A corollary is that for small tables, indexes may never be useful.  If the data fits on one page, it might be just as fast to scan the page using the `where` filter as using an index.

That is, if the selectivity of the query is greater than the inverse of the average number of records on a data page, then an index is probably not going to be useful.  This comes as close as possible to a "general" rule, but read on.

The *type* of index makes a difference as well.  If you have the condition `is_qualified` and only 0.1% of records meet this condition, then the index might prove useful.  Or, if 1% are qualified but the records are very large so there are only 10 on a page, then index is probably useful.  Or, if `is_qualified` is the first column in a clustered index, than all the values with `1` are on a handful of pages.  With a clustered index, even a 30% selectivity for `is_qualified = 1` is going to mean reading only 30% of the data pages -- which should cut the time for many queries by two-thirds.

Of course, this leaves out the use of indexes for joins and order by -- situations where even 100% selectivity may still benefit from an index.  However, your question seemed geared toward filtering in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do some research and reading on using indexes.  Even from your own example, you expect an index on the "id" column because you are looking for a specific ONE...  But then its not important to have an index on IS_QUALIFIED because it can have only 2 possible values...  But the ID with alpha-numeric can have billions of values.

Indexes are used to help quickly narrow down and find records without having to get to the raw data pages to pull qualified record based on common criteria you expect to be pulling out.  Indexes should be considered to even have multiple columns based on the types of common queries you expect to run.

Lets take some of your data scenario columns and assume a table is a child table per "id", has the "is_qualified" and "othertype" (your values 0-9), along with some other things.. maybe such as date of something, or description of the "other type".

if you only had an index on the ID, then all the "ID" records would be grouped together and that is fine, once you get to them a quick run through those gets you results.

But now, let say you are looking for all IDs that have "Is_Qualified" = 1 AND also the "othertype" column is 3.  You can't get them quickly, there is no correlation from one to another... but if you had a multiple key index of (is_qualified, othertype, id ), then you could quickly jump to only those records of Is_Qualified = 1 and othertype = 3 and then you have all the IDs ready to go.

Apply this to a table that has a few million records to query, and run queries without indexes and you will greatly appreciate their purpose, and also learn to design well, meaningful indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It is more important how many rows exist in the table and not whether they have 2 or 10 possible values. For table with less than 200-300 rows, there is no need of index. If you have 1 million rows, it is good to have index even if the column has only 0 and 1 - you will avoid full scan. For example, if only 500 of 1M rows are 1 - the query will skip scanning 999,500 rows.